# Jmeter: Maps in Jmeter

Tags: loops, http, jmeter, maps, sample

```
--LoopController
  |
  |--Http Sampler One
  |
  |--Http Sampler Two

--Http Sampler Three
```

**Http Sampler One** gives a json response as *{"data": ["foo", "bar"]}*.

**Http Sampler Two** gives a json response as *{"data": "jeba"}*.

I want to map **jeba -> ["foo", "bar"]**

I want a mapping variable **myMap** wherein if I pass the key **"jeba"** I get **["foo", "bar"]**.

I want to create this mapping for every request in the loop controller, I want to use this mapping variable in Http Sampler Three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible options:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the Request 1 and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.putObject('data1', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data)
   ```
2. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the Request 2 and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def data2 =  new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data
   def myMap = [:]
   myMap.put(data2, vars.get('data1'))
   vars.putObject('myMap', myMap)
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to read the value by key using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.getObject('myMap')['jeba'],)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Maps in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-maps)